# Why do I have this "Undefined Index error: id in ..."?

Tags: php

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\bidding\view\ctgryedit.php on line 134

Am getting this notice while doing edit operation . the code which i had given is

```
     <?php
     $cid=$_GET['id'];
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die("error in connection");
mysql_select_db('bidding',$con) or die("error in db");
$sql="select * from category where `catgry_id`='$cid'";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res); 
     ?>
```

Am sending the value using query string.... Plz anybody help me to solve dis error...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for array indices before blindly using them. Try something like

```
$cid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null; // or some other sane default
```

In regards to why your script is failing, are you sure you are calling your script (or a script that includes yours) via HTTP with `?id=something` in the query string?

Comment: I think your approach is better, as it reduces it to a line and is better readable (subjective). I use this kind of checks as well to avoid undefined indexes and missing values.

Answer (score 0):

I come to think of 2 posibilities:

1. A typo: Maybe you mispelled parameter name, or it is being sent over POST instead of GET by error OR
2. Parameter list is empty because you are calling the script directly ctgryedit.php instead of ctgryedit.php?id=foo

In second case, you can check if you have any GET data by:

```
if ($_GET) {
    //Your code
}
else {
    //File has been called directly without any parameter
}
```

It may sound absurd but those posibilities are the most common bugs you can find and the last to think of by programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GET method 
Check your url it should be like

```
localhost/pageName.php?id=5
```

if not there is a problem with your form 
check if your form method is 'GET' and 
you have specified name attribute for the id

```
<form method='get' id='thisForm'>
<input type='text' name='id' />
<input type='submit' value="Submit" />
</form>
```

if id is shown in URL

then

```
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
     $cid=$_GET['id'];

     // SQL query
 }
```